# Angular scope changes in service not affecting template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've set up a service that can display a status message on a template.

```
.service('displayStatus', function ()
{
    var statusTime = 5000;
    var self = this;

    this.show = function ($scope, type, msg)
    {
        $scope.status = {
            type: type,
            msg: msg
        }

        self.timer = setTimeout(function ()
        {
            self.hide($scope);

        }, statusTime);
    }

    this.hide = function ($scope)
    {
        $scope.status = {
            type: null,
            msg: null
        }
        console.log('hid it', $scope);
    }
})
```

Whenever I want an error to show up, I just call `displayStatus.show($scope, 'error', 'Uh oh! An error!')`. It's the setTimeout that's giving me problems. While the template will update based on the changes I make in "this.show", after waiting 5 seconds and attempting to hide it, the changes don't apply, even though the console.log shows I'm altering $scope.

Why aren't my changes showing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the body of your event handler in [`$scope.$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope), or better yet, use the [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service to do your timeouts, which does this for you. After calling your function, `$apply` triggers a `$digest` cycle, which is how angular detects changes to the model.

```
.service('displayStatus', function ($timeout)
{
    var statusTime = 5000;
    var self = this;

    this.show = function ($scope, type, msg)
    {
        $scope.status = {
            type: type,
            msg: msg
        }

        self.timer = $timeout(function ()
        {
            self.hide($scope);
        }, statusTime);
    }

    this.hide = function ($scope)
    {
        $scope.status = {
            type: null,
            msg: null
        }
        console.log('hid it', $scope);
    }
})
```